# What is the name for numbers using a comma for a decimal separator versus a dot

Tags: terminology

I am curious to know if there is a specific name for numbers that use a comma for a decimal separator and a dot for a thousands separator as opposed to numbers that are the reverse.

For example: 4.048,5 vs 4,048.5

Comment: I don't see any reason why there would be a specific name, it just depends on your country.

Comment: The only time I saw this reversal of notation was in the French-language  section of a pamphlet on the use of a slide rule I bought (in the Stone Age.) I assumed it was a matter of  national style.

Answer (score 1):

There's a name for the *symbol* used to separate the integer part from the fractional part: it's called the [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark). Not sure if there's a terminology for the numbers that use a particular convention for the decimal mark. Besides the two examples you cite, the Wikipedia article mentions several other 'styles' for displaying numbers.

Comment: Or more generally, allowing for other bases, a *radix point* (even when it’s a comma).